# php mysql function for inserting records

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code that I am studying but don't see the purpose of a certain line.

```
public function insertRecords($table, $data){
    //setup some variables for fields and values
    $fields = "";
    $values = "";

    //populate them
    foreach($data as $f => $v){
        $fields .= "`$f`,";
        $values .= (is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) ? $v . "," : "'$v',";
    }

    //remove our trailing ,
    $fields = substr($fields, 0, -1);
    //remove our trailing ,
    $values = substr($values, 0, -1);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO $table ({$fields}) values({$values})";
    //echo $insert
    $this->executeQuery($insert);
    return true;
}
```

I don't see the purpose of:

```
intval($v) == $v))
```

In the ternary operator. What I understand is, if the integer value of $v is the same as $v do blah. Of course the integer value of $v is going to be equal to $v. It's the current value in the current iteration. Is my understanding incorrect?

I already know that if intval() doesn't return a integer it defaults to a string in the ternary operator.

Comment: If `$v` is an integer, don't wrap it in quotes. If it's not (it's a string), wrap it in quotes. Depending on what you expect the value of `$v` to be, you may or may not need that line. But it seems that `$v` is a reasonably flexible value that could be a string or an integer.

Comment: It is merely ensuring that when $v is converted to an int, it still looks like $v. So, if $v is 3, intval(3)==3 is true. If $v is 3.1, intval(3.1)==3.1 is false. Obviously, any $v that is not a number will be false. I have a feeling that intval(null)==null will return true, but I haven't checked it.

Comment: Wouldn't it been wise to use the === strict comparison as a string "0" will be converted to an integer, for accuracy?

Comment: Almost like JavaScript's parseFloat and parseInt funcions don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.

That line is merely a method of checking whether the variable $v is indeed an integer. Because if it is any other data-type the value would differ from that intval() operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is using [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) just because it's checking for the value entered to be an **integer** rather than a string wich would not be allowed in your query either for column datatype and for security purpose

> intval — Get the integer value of a variable

Answer (score 0):

`is_numeric($v)` returns true if $v is a number (e.g. 234233) or numeric string (e.g. "234233"), whereas `intval($v) == $v` returns true if $v is an integer.

The first makes sure $v is a numeric in any way and seconds checks if $v is an integer.

I guess you could drop `is_numeric($v)`